# Make Ruby File.open().read same output with PHP file_get_contents()

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like my ruby `File.open(FILE PATH).read` be same output as what I am getting from PHP `file_get_contents(FILE PATH)`

Right now,

**Ouput in PHP**

> %PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (þÿ) /Creator (þÿ) /Producer (þÿQt 4.8.4 (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)) /CreationDate (D:20130701144043) >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /SA true /SM 0.02 /ca 1.0 /CA 1.0 /AIS false /SMask /None>> endobj 5 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R /Resources 9 0 R /Annots 10 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 595 842] >> endobj 9 0 obj << /ColorSpace << /PCSp 5 0 R /CSp /DeviceRGB /CSpg /DeviceGray >> /ExtGState << /GSa 4 0 R >> /Pattern << >> /Font << >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 10 0 obj [ ] endobj 7 0 obj << /Length 8 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream xœÔ½K6É²¥5ß¿â#‘íîá×q µzÀ1@ÅM¨6âÀ€¿Ïz–G¾a;³…8GÝ§Ê*Òßws»Û²÷*üÇÿîÏÿôüùwÿþ?þoþºÿï¿ÿÿH*©§ý?øßÿ<ÊüºÊþÇ™¯¯>–þçÏ_ÿüÇ¿ýù·ü‡üýÿüßûGî_}ÿyý«þàûg÷üý¯ÿøwû…þ±)ÿñßÿWú§ÿóOùó_êßþ—?ÿÍ«ÿóßß¿ÁÿüÇ\ÝË6þõïø¯ùJ£]svÑÿå_yøþÇýŸýù_yÑëëªWi×Ø/zþëÿ“ý·ÏŸfÿoüÓÿ¿Ëÿé£üãÏÿþ?üãäËÿß~Ýò¼î¿ý'þð?ó¯ÿ}äÖ¿’v7ÿ¹®ùU×5ëÒùŒ<ê×˜£Š^ëW-e\œ€èùk•Ô×Ÿ«Õ¯YµÀõgä>¾ôP{ùjsÕÖ ¦¯:;kè¿÷ºøÇ¿øÍëkæ•¯?×(_#­Yºž®íëê)7QÛW¹ÖÊKÔ«}å´êˆTÖ(EoÕëu>ËWJ%éGúZi”‘EMú=½XñÛ•š×¨¬‘VÓ5H¬¡7j£÷1ÿˆšõCŸuÕü5Ê½ÔÒõÎúý¹×øÐsúšI/â§µò*¹þ)K»ÚF×~•²¼Ì%v×{ìýÐ[ç¬›*ºÖèô®¤ÿStjŸ­Oö£•YN*kÔñ¥KTÚùtúõ>³¨Kç–{c§»Î¶]KÔÙ¿fóº¼F__iqæei÷²¶÷Ð]­%¾E_>jíõù£•>ÓŸ+‰?òJâŸmûªÚü)úüZCŸ¸Ì7â]eÝžOeæÂÉ4qSËU'“’ö@r€µ«D•–¾ô‹ã«´R$üðdíÐµÚlí‚Ëª¸ìJE»º´c­ä17ßè—Ö©æ›ùÅzù|nšú^Q· ûËóü-u¿1Ýû„øìWåÛuÎ­¯‹]ÍY{-ž'ˆßæ˜³Ô">‡ý-ý:Óôg¯¬ƒ÷Ú×ªeïGÖÙŽzÁ§Y}êk¿ïÀ¥÷¯¢÷¯¬·¨ìi*o×¦Î¹‹1Ùª­ÜŒ‡ê=•Ž¸–6òxš;¯

**In Ruby**

> %PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��) /Creator (��) /Producer (��Qt 4.8.4 (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)) /CreationDate (D:20130701144043) >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /SA true /SM 0.02 /ca 1.0 /CA 1.0 /AIS false /SMask /None>> endobj 5 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R /Resources 9 0 R /Annots 10 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 595 842] >> endobj 9 0 obj << /ColorSpace << /PCSp 5 0 R /CSp /DeviceRGB /CSpg /DeviceGray >> /ExtGState << /GSa 4 0 R >> /Pattern << >> /Font << >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 10 0 obj [ ] endobj 7 0 obj << /Length 8 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream x�ԽK�6ɲ�5߿�#�����q� �z�1@�M�6�����z�G�a;��8Gݧ�*��ws�۲�*���������w��?�o�������H*���?���<�����Ǚ��>����*��ǿ�����������G�*}��y�����g�������w����)����W����O��_����?������߿����\��6������J�]sv���_y�������_y���Wi��/z������ϟf�o������������?������~����'��?��}�ֿ�v7����U�5����<�ט��^�W-e\����k��ן�կY���g�>��

I already tried this in Ruby(fyi, I am using RoR framework.)

```
open(FILE PATH, "r:ISO-8859-15:UTF-8", {:col_sep => "t", :row_sep => "rn", :headers => :first_row}) do |f| 
  (f.read)
end
```

Comment: Can you try by putting put `#encoding:utf-8` on top of the .rb file ?

Comment: It's fairly clear your end goal is *not* to have the either of the shown outputs (because they are useless without some stage which interprets this data). It is quite easy to end up rejecting a correct solution because you are looking at it through something with different conversion and display characteristics. In other words your file reads in Ruby might be ok, and you could miss that. It might help to explain what you are trying to do with this data - for instance are you trying to serve PDF content via HTTP?

Comment: Your example `open` statement is very likely wrong for reading a PDF file. A simple `open(FILE PATH, "rb")`, without the options for reading CSV, will probably do.

Comment: @priti, it is still the same.
NeilSlater, it is just the same doing open(file path, "rb").read

Comment: @Rod Medina: That's very likely because the problem is not with the file reading, but with how you are then using and/or displaying the returned string variable.

Comment: I am sending this file via soap. If I just send what I got from open().read, I am getting the `Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Server) Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfe (at char #835, byte #127)`. If I do 

`open(FILE PATH, "r:ISO-8859-15:UTF-8", {:col_sep => "t", :row_sep => "rn", :headers => :first_row}) do |f| 
  (f.read)
end`

I am getting an error of `Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Server) Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content`